# Why does console show e.explicitOriginalTarget.value as set on paste or cut event in prototype.js but evaluate as empty string

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, prototypejs, dom-events

[check out this JSFiddle in firefox for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ATCE/3/)

open up console and enter input into one of the fields, if you then cut the text out, check the values in console.

If you `console.log(e.explicitOriginalTarget);` you can see it contains a property called value that indeed contains the new correct value after cut for the input.  However, on the very next line, if you try to directly `console.log(e.explicitOriginalTarget.value);` ,the property, the previous value of the input as it was before the cut is logged.

No idea how this is happening?  Any one have any ideas?

I've tried doing a typeof e.explicitOriginalTarget.value and it is returning "string" which I expect.

If anyone can think of any other idea on how to check whether an input had all text removed on a cut I'm open to those as well.  I'm kind of being forced to use prototype here and am relatively new to it so I might be overlooking some built in functionality.

Comment: @Huangism thanks for the post but that doesn't solve the problem.  It still just gives the value prior to the cut.  Basically I either need that as well as the bit thats to copied to the clipboard, or an after cut event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#cut-event) says:

> The cut event fires before the selected data is removed.

Hence, when the event fires, the `.value` will be still the one before the cut.
If you `console.log` the event/event target and *later* inspect it (by clicking on it ;), the change of course will have been made as the event is long done processing at this point. Remember: The target you're logging is a live DOM node.

I'd have a `setTimeout(..., 0)` to check what the value is like after the cut as a stupidly easy work-around.

Or work with `input` instead of `cut` events, if my requirements allowed that...